# How to change existing repository in Bamboo build plan?

Tags: repository, bamboo

How to change existing repository in Bamboo build plan?

**Note:** I don't want to use add repository option, I have to replace old repo with new one.

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 1):

It is an "add and remove" to replace the repo.

1. Click on the plan
2. **Actions > Configure Plan**
3. Click the **Repositories** tab (as shown below)
4. Click **Add Repository** and follow the steps to add a new one.
5. The first repository in the list is the "default", so you can now remove the old one.

[image]